# How to get the value of an Excel range in C#, not the value of the cells

Tags: c#, excel

How can I get the row and column of the upper left corner and lower right corner of an Excel.Range in C#?

For example, if I use the following statement to set a Range:

```
Excel.Range oRng = oSheet.get_Range("C2", "E6");
```

How can I get "C2:E6" or the equivalent from oRng?
I tried the Value property which learn.microsoft.com says "Returns or sets the value of the specified range" but neither of the following statements worked:

```
tbxOutput.AppendText($"range.Value = {range.Value}\r\n");
tbxOutput.AppendText($"range.Value = {range.Value.ToString()}\r\n");
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that in C#. I tried the following:

tbxOutput.AppendText($"UsedRange.Address = {range.Address[true, true, ReferenceStyle.xlA1, Missing.Value, Missing.Value]}\r\n");

tbxOutput.AppendText($"UsedRange.Address = {range.Address[true, true, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Missing.Value, Missing.Value]}\r\n");

In both cases, an IntelliSense message said that the name (ReferenceStyle or XlReferenceStyle) does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Figured it out...the correct syntax for the third argument is:
Excel.XlReferenceStyle
so the complete, correct code line is:
tbxOutput.AppendText($"UsedRange.Address = {range.Address[true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Missing.Value, Missing.Value]}\r\n");